# ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package while try to run package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following project structure. When I try to run code code from test.py i have ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package.

[image: Project structure]

Where am I wrong? I also would like this package on any computer, so I probably should figure out a path problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a relative import. This should work fine:

```py
from logic import window

# Do stuff
# ...

window.player()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an empty `__init__.py` to `robbi` directory.

Comment: Really? I cannot see it on the screenshot.

Comment: It's before test.py file

Comment: You should add `robbi/__init__.py`, not only in sub-directories.